# Can I override the PHP function echo()?

Tags: php, laravel

Can I override the PHP function echo()?

I need append text to echo

```
echo "text";

function echo($string)
{echo $string ." in line : ". __LINE__;}
```

Comment: you mean you want change the function name as echo?

Comment: You could look at how to use output buffering so that you can capture the output instead.

Comment: `echo` is not a function it's a language construct. It's also a [reserved word](http://php.net/reserved) in PHP. You cannot reuse reserved words.

Comment: I need append text to echo  return

Comment: Just create another function e.g. `dump('some info here')` instead of trying to override `echo`

Comment: Stab into the dark: you're trying to debug where a particular piece of output is coming from? You better do that with a debugger and setting breakpoints. That may be slightly tricky to set up the first time, but is an invaluable tool once you know it.

Comment: yes I use xdebug but there are a lot of loop and file